# Did Lakshmi exist before Kshir Sagar manthan?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi, samudra-manthan

Some scriptures state that Vishnu married Lakshmi, who came from churning of ocean of milk.

Did Lakshmi exist before that event?

Comment: There are multiple Vishnus. Maha Lakshmi is there with Para Vasudev!

Comment: @Pratimaputra Yeah, because I accept only I can validate by myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, she existed. It is the case of disappearing and reappearing again after some time.

The Brahma Vaivarta Purana gives a story according to which she existed before the Samudra Manthana too.

The story, in short is like this:

Durvasa Muni, a devotee of Lord Vishnu, once received a flower garland from Lord Vishnu as Prasad of Puja. While the Muni went to Swarga, he gifted that garland to Indra, the king of the Devas. Indra, instead of honoring it appropriately, placed the garland around Airavata's neck (Airavata is the elephant mount of Lord Indra).

This made Durvasa furious, and is usual with him, he cursed Indra that Lakshmi will abandon the Swarga and thereby all it's prosperity will be lost.

Till that point Lakshmi was residing in the heavens as Swarga Lakshmi (one of the Ashta Lakshmis).

> Parijata flower garland which Vishnu presented to the Muni. Out of
>   arrogance, Indra placed the garland around the neck of Iraavata-the
>   Elephant Carrier of Indra! The infuriated Muni felt that this
>   sacrilegious and irrevernt act of Indra was not only indicative of
>   disrespect for himself but also an act of unpardonable profanity to
>   Bhagavan Vishnu! He therefore cursed Indra saying that an invaluable
>   gift rewarded to Durvasa by Narayana was parted with and out of
>   consideration to Indra who ignored its inherent worth. **Hence, the
>   root cause of Lakshmi, who was the Form of Prosperity, should abandon
>   Swarga forth with.**

Lord Vishnu advised Lakshmi to stay in the ocean until she reappears from the churning.

This is mentioned in the following passage:

> **Having explained on these lines, Vishnu advised Devi Lakshmi to stay in Ksheera Samudra till Devas and Danavas did Amrita Manthana or
>   churning of the Ocean.** Soon thereafter, the Sagara Manthana
>   commenced with Mandara Mountain as kaashtha or the Churning rod;
>   Kurmavatara / the incarnation of Bhagavan Vishnu as Tortoise to
>   balance the Mountain, Sesha Naaga as the rope with which to rotate the
>   kaashtha, and Devas and Danavas as the Churning Parties

Source - [Essence of Brahma Vaivarta Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahma%20vaivartha/bookview.php?chapnum=16)

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Iraavata came out during samundra manthan. Unless Brahma Vaivarta Purana mentioned just an elephant. But as you have quoted from the text, it would be interesting to see whether it mentions Iraavata came out during manthan